# MySQL: mysqldump to generate database backup

Tags: php, mysql

I have had written the following snippet that **generates the `mysql` database dump and saves it on the server**:

```
public function save_db_backup()
{
    $DBUSER=$this->db->username;
    $DBPASSWD=$this->db->password;
    $DATABASE=$this->db->database;

    $filename = $DATABASE . "-" . date("Y-m-d_H-i-s") . ".sql.gz";

    $save_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/application/assets/db_backups/' . $filename;

    $cmd = "mysqldump -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD $DATABASE | gzip --best > " . $save_path;

    exec( $cmd );
}
```

It has been **working fine on my other server**. But after moving my site to this new server, it has suddenly **stopped working** i.e. database backup file is not being saved at the path specified. Also, I have checked `exec` **is enabled** on the server plus the **directory is readable and also writeable**:

```
 is_readable($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/application/assets/db_backups/') // true
 is_writable($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/application/assets/db_backups/') // true
```

I have checked and the database credentials are alright. I have tried with the path to `mysqldump` and that didn't work either:

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/mysqldump -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD $DATABASE | gzip --best > " . $save_path;
```

What problem could there possibly be?

Comment: are these script runs from cron job ?

Comment: Just to be sure: don't ever put database backups in a location accessible from the internet. They will be indexed by google.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Yes I would be using cron job later but for now I am just trying it manually and it's not generating the backup.

Answer (score 0):

You should check what user launches the command, and then if the dir is readable and also writeable by THAT user.
If you are launching it from a PHP script, it's the probable cause.